# How to pass multiple $http promise under $q

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have a bunch of urls I want to make GET calls one after another and then join the return data for each url.

I am using the following code to combine multiple promises and then passing it under $q.all.

```
var urls = _.map(urlArray, function(pUrl) {
  var promise_obj = $http.get(pUrl);
  return promise_obj;
});

$q.all(urls)
  .then(function(responses) {
      ctrl.points = _.reduce(responses, function(data, response) {
        if (elem == undefined) {
          return data.concat(response.data);
        } else {
          return data.concat(response.data[elem]);
        }
      }, []);

    }
  });
```

But this does not work since the urls variable passed to $q.all is empty. I am assuming the reason is $http.get call is asynchronous so byt the time I am calling the $q.all the value of urls is empty.

The issue is I can have as many urls so I would not want to chain the responses. Any idea how I can get this working?

Comment: i think problem is in reduce, not on map though.

Comment: Where did "elem" come from?

Comment: If `urls` is empty when you call `$q.all`, then something is wrong in the way you create this array. It's not related to the fact that it contains promises

Comment: Are you sure `urlArray` actually contains anything? Have you added a `.catch` to your `$q.all` call to see if one of the promises rejects?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code slightly, here's  a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/mutezefaqe/1/edit) (albeit using `$timeout` instead of `$http`) to showcase the changes made.

But seeing as how `$timeout(func)` and `$http.get` both return a promise (and I've done what you're doing multiple times in the past with an array of `$http.get`'s), I would look into why the `urls/urlArray` end up being `undefined` when being passed into `$q.all()`.

I believe the error lies somewhere before you reach $q.all. Possibly a rejected promise.

Docs for `$q.all`:

> Returns a single promise that will be resolved with an array/hash of values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index/key in the promises array/hash. **If any of the promises is resolved with a rejection, this resulting promise will be rejected with the same rejection value.**

Try adding a `.catch` in the promise chain.